# How to get String from a Java file to a different one in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, variables

I have this code, I wan to transfer the variables from the java file of java_2 to java_2_1, I
try to use the method extends, but it doesn't work:

```
    public class java_2 extends java {//There is java_1, which is the first, but
                                  //the String transfer is only between java_2.java and
                                  //java_2_1.java;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dise_2);
            botonRETURN1();
            botonAHEAD1();

//I WANT TO TRANSFER ALL THIS VARIABLES TO java_2_1, but don't know how.
            final EditText A,B,C,D,E,F;
            String AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF,G;
            A=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.A);
            B=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.B);
            C=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.C);
            D=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.D);
            E=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.E);
            F=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.F);
            AA=A.getText().toString();
            BB=B.getText().toString();
            CC=C.getText().toString();
            DD=D.getText().toString();
            EE=E.getText().toString();
            FF=F.getText().toString();
            G=AA+BB+CC+DD+EE+FF;
        }
```

TO:

```
public class java_2_1 extends java_2{//I try doing this heritance thing, but it doesn't work;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

}
```

Comment: thats not going to work you can either make all the data you want static or set a getter method.

Comment: Ho do you use the getter method?.

Comment: Simple oop make a function return a value try searching getters and setters java

Comment: I wonder why people try to create apps for Android if they have no understanding of OOP and Java.